# swift - ForEach loop with state

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui, state

If I have this code:

```
@State var n = 3
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action:{
            if self.n == 3 {
                self.n = 5
            } else {
                self.n = 3
            }
        }) {
            Text("Click me")
        }
        ForEach(1..<self.n+1) { i in
            Text(String(i))
        }
    }
}
```

I expect this code to toggle between `1` `2` `3` and `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` on the screen when you click the button, however it only shows `1` `2` `3`. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The form of `ForEach` that you have used is fine if the number of items is constant, but if the Views might change, then you need to either provide items that conform to the protocol `Identifiable`, or use the form of `ForEach` that provides the `id:`:

```
ForEach(1..<self.n+1, id: \.self) { i in
    Text(String(i))
}
```

The value passed as `id` is a `KeyPath` that tells SwiftUI which property of the item to use as its identifier.  In the case of an `Int`, you can just use the `Int`'s value which can be accessed through the `.self` property.

SwiftUI uses the identifiers to know when items in the `ForEach` have been added or removed, thus it needs them for you to be able to see the change.