# Create new row in table when button is clicked Swift UI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to insert a row in my table when I click my "Add Sets" button. TableRow is a very simple view that is just an HStack with a text field and two text input fields. I am stuck and there isn't much online for this issue. Thank You

```
struct ExerciseCard: View {
    @State private var exercise : String = "Bench Press"
    @State private var sets : Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Enter Exercise", text: $exercise).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .frame(width: 300)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            HStack{
                Group{
                    Text("Set")
                    Text("Weight")
                    Text("Reps")
                }.padding(.horizontal, 30)
                
            }
            VStack{
                
                ForEach(0..<sets){ number in
                    TableRow()
                    
                    
                }
            }.padding(.bottom, 5)
            
            Button(action: {
                self.sets += 1
            }) {
                Text("Add Set")
                    .frame(minWidth: 200)
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.6))
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
}

struct ExerciseCard_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExerciseCard()
    }
}
```

Comment: `ForEach(0..<sets, id: \.self) { number in
                    TableRow()
                    
                    
                }`

Comment: Thank you! that worked! I am very new to swift ui if you can't tell haha

Comment: If you upvote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63144869/1630618), I can close your question as a duplicate of it.